# IE8 Support with media queries using respond.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**Heres the design**
http://vvcap.net/db/OuxLOYioWmjIAavL5N9U.htp

**Here's a demo!**
http://designobvio.us/GoldGrid2/

In chrome and FF the media queries work just fine of course.  I really want the effects to work in IE8.  I tried using Respond.js with no luck :(

Am I dumb?  I've new to media queries; thus respond.js is foreign also.

I've read through many other similar articles, still no luck.
[HTML5 Boilerplate + Media Queries not working in IE8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8240107/html5-boilerplate-media-queries-not-working-in-ie8) this one was helpful yet still not fruitful.

Any one have any ideas on where i can go from here?

Comment: I've had trouble getting respond and selectivzr to work together, although I think what failed in that case was selectivzr. I solved it by using the very latest versions of both. The JS-files I've successfully used can be found here: http://code.google.com/p/html5base/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fjs the order in which they are included matters, see here: http://code.google.com/p/html5base/source/browse/trunk/modules/head.php

Comment: Also, in your demo, you're trying to include "responsive.js" which doesn't event exist.

Comment: I fixed the responsive.js error.  Nothing changed.  I believe that my heirarchy if correct my respond.js is after selectivr.js.  Also these are teh most current versions.  Any thoughts beyond here?  I've updated teh site also

Comment: Have you tried with the versions I suggested? I'm using selectivizr 1.0.3b. I'm pretty sure I tried 1.0.2 which didn't work (which is what you're using).

Answer (score 0):

Well i have one solution for this ,we can use % i.e fluid layout for these two browser 
i.e IE 8 & IE 7

Comment: Using a fluid layout doesn't replace the need for media queries / respond.js  Fluid layout is not automatically responsive.